# Is there a way to set a token for another process?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, token

There is SetThreadToken() function but no such function as "SetProcessToken()".

Is there a way to set a token for another process? How to write "SetProcessToken()"?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can, using the undocumented [`NtSetInformationProcess`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Process/NtSetInformationProcess.html) function, however once the process has started running the process token is locked and can no longer be modified. You must therefore start the process with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` creation flag, set the process token, then resume the process using `ResumeThread()`. In order to set the process token the caller must have and enable the `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` privilege.

Code such as the following should be sufficient:

```
// A few required typedefs

typedef enum _PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS
{
    ProcessBasicInformation,
    ProcessQuotaLimits,
    ProcessIoCounters,
    ProcessVmCounters,
    ProcessTimes,
    ProcessBasePriority,
    ProcessRaisePriority,
    ProcessDebugPort,
    ProcessExceptionPort,
    ProcessAccessToken,
    ProcessLdtInformation,
    ProcessLdtSize,
    ProcessDefaultHardErrorMode,
    ProcessIoPortHandlers,
    ProcessPooledUsageAndLimits,
    ProcessWorkingSetWatch,
    ProcessUserModeIOPL,
    ProcessEnableAlignmentFaultFixup,
    ProcessPriorityClass,
    ProcessWx86Information,
    ProcessHandleCount,
    ProcessAffinityMask,
    ProcessPriorityBoost,
    MaxProcessInfoClass
} PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS, *PPROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS;

typedef struct _PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN
{
    HANDLE Token;
    HANDLE Thread;
} PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN, *PPROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN;

typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI * NtSetInformationProcess) (HANDLE processHandle, PROCESS_INFORMATION_CLASS infoClass, PVOID info, ULONG infoLength);


// Assume we have a handle to an existing process: targetProcessHandle, started in a suspended state, and a new token: newToken to assign to this process.

// First we must enable SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege.
// Note: The user under which this runs must already hold the privilege, this only enables it (it is initially disabled by default).
LUID luid;
LookupPrivilegeValue(0, SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME, &luid);
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES privs;
privs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
privs.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
privs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

HANDLE myToken;
if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &myToken))
{
    wprintf("Unable to open own process token to enable permissions\n");
    return FALSE;
}
if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(myToken, FALSE, &privs, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 0, 0))
{
    wprintf("Error setting token privileges: 0x%08x\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(myToken);
    return FALSE;
}
// Even if AdjustTokenPrivileges returns TRUE, it may not have succeeded, check last error top confirm
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
{
    wprintf("Unable to enable a required privilege\n");
    CloseHandle(myToken);
    return FALSE;
}
CloseHandle(myToken);

PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN tokenInfo;
tokenInfo.Token = newToken;
tokenInfo.Thread = 0;

// Get a handle to ntdll
HMODULE ntdll = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");

// And a pointer to the NtSetInformationProcess function
NtSetInformationProcess setInfo = (NtSetInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(ntdll,"NtSetInformationProcess");
NTSTATUS setInfoResult = setInfo(targetProcessHandle, ProcessAccessToken, &tokenInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN));
if (setInfoResult < 0)
{
    wprintf(L"Error setting token: 0x%08x\n", setInfoResult);
    return FALSE;
}

FreeLibrary(ntdll);

// You can now resume the target process' main thread here using ResumeThread().

return TRUE;
```

Comment: @Iridium why can't one use NtSuspendProcess and then set token for already running process

Comment: @T.s.Arun - If I recall (though it was almost 9 years ago now) it didn't work on an already-running process hence my assumption that the token is locked once the process starts running, however I don't think I ever tried suspending a running process then trying to change the token, so maybe that does work - give it a try and let us know!

Comment: @Iridium I tried. I am getting error code 50 after converting NTSTATUS to win32. "The request is not supported. 
You think it is possible to use PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx to intercept process creation, replace token and then let the creation routine complete. Is there a channel where I can discuss this with you? Perhaps email(arun4sym@gmail.com is my ID)?

Comment: @T.s.Arun - Unfortunately I'm by no means an expert on this topic, I was only able to post this answer because I just happened to be reverse-engineering an application that used this technique at the time the question was asked. You will likely get much better help by posting an appropriate question on SO where those who have more knowledge on the subject than I do will be able to answer.

Comment: @Iridium Thank you for your response though. Your answer has been helpful.

Comment: In the words of Nathan Hale, "I have but one upvote to give."  I used `NtSetInformationProcess()` in the CubicleSoft [command-line CreateProcess tool](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/createprocess-windows) to start child processes on Windows in a completely brand new way that's never been done before.  Thank you for making it possible to do that.  While some aspects of the answer are slightly flawed (in really minor ways such as structure naming conflicts with the Windows SDK), it was the necessary piece of missing information that I needed for that project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. get your one token by `OpenProcessToken()`, duplicate the token with `DuplicateTokenEx()`, set the duplicated token as you like with `SetTokenInformation()`, and create a new process with this token by `CreateProcessAsUser()`

you need for this the `SeTcbPrivilege`, `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` and `SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege`

Comment: @user143233 , so the privileges are set for the current process or the process handle you earlier got with `OpenProcess()` ?

Comment: The new process. You cerate a new process with this token. After DuplicateTokenEx() you have a token that is not associated with any process. changing it has no effect, but once you create a new process with this token, the new process gets the settings of the token.

Answer (score 1):

A process only has one security token, the primary, which is a copy of the user's security token.

Threads have a second security token, the impersonation token. Processes do not have these, only threads. You cannot make a process impersonate another user's security token.