# How to impersonate an existing process with win32 API?

Tags: authentication, winapi, process, win32-process

I want to run an application in different processes using each logged-in user's credentials, without creating brand new processes with the Win32 API `CreateProcessAsUserA()`, because the application takes roughly a minute to launch, which is unacceptable in terms of performance.

- **Plan A:** Start a few stand-up processes before user requests come in. Impersonate the existing process with given user credentials.
  How to do that?
- **Plan B:** I'm open to hear other ideas.

Comment: Impersonation does not affect everything in a process so it depends on what your application does.

Comment: Doesn't impersonation affect access granted to the process, e.g. to read/write files?

Comment: Yes but not CreateProcess and certain shell functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented/undocumented way of achieving what you are requesting. There is a hack way to do this but with serious security compromise.

If you have right to impersonate other user, it means your process is running at highest privilege in Windows. What you can do is following

1. Process A creates multiple copies of process B (which takes time to launch) with the same rights as process A. So essentially process B also has right to impersonate.
2. Process B will set up an LPC mechanism (pipe/sockets/whatever) that process A can write to. Process B will wait indefinitely until it receives request from process A.
3. When the request comes in, process A will get the user information and pass that to process B using the LPC mechanism.
4. Process B will then impersonate the user and carry out the task and terminate.

Under no circumstances should this be used in retail product as this is a hack that can be exploited easily depending on what the process B is doing. If you are going to ship a product with this hack, please let us know the name so that we do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your process has only one thread or not many threads, you could use [`SetThreadToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadtoken).

- First, [`LogonUserA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) or some other functions are used to get a user token.
- Then, [`DuplicateToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-duplicatetoken) converts it into an impersonation token.
- Get the thread handle, and finally call `SetThreadToken`.

Here is a simple example.(Already remove the error checking for brevity)

Existing process:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    cout << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;//For example: I get currentthreadid = 17608 this time.
    getchar();
    char user[100] = { 0 };
    DWORD size = 100;
    GetUserNameA(user, &size);
    cout << user << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

SetThreadToken.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hToken, DToken;
    BOOL i = LogonUserA("user","domain","password", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,&hToken);
    HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS,false,17608);
    DuplicateToken(hToken, SecurityImpersonation,&DToken);
    SetThreadToken(&hThread, DToken);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to set a token for the process, There is an undocumented method `NtSetInformationProcess` in `ntdll.dll`, try the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141997/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-token-for-another-process) to set the Process Access Token.