# Is it possible to impersonate a process's access token?

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, impersonation

The typical way to impersonate a user, is to call LogOnUser() to get the access token of the user and pass this token to ImpersonateLoggedOnUser() for impersonation.

However, this only impersonates the user **for the calling thread**. Is there a way to impersonate or change a process's access token (primary token)? Support I'm accessing a network share and multiple threads are spawned to access different parts of that network share. Do I have to impersonate the remote user (who has access to that share) in all those threads? Or is there a way to "impersonate" the process first, so that when the new threads are spawned they already have the access by inheriting the process primary token automatically?

Answer (score 2):

no, this is not possible. formal exist *`ProcessAccessToken`* information class for *`NtSetInformationProcess`*. it take `PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN` structure as input. it not documented, but declared in *`ntddk.h`*

> ```
> //
> // Process Security Context Information
> //  NtSetInformationProcess using ProcessAccessToken
> // PROCESS_SET_ACCESS_TOKEN access to the process is needed
> // to use this info level.
> //
>
> typedef struct _PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN {
>
>     //
>     // Handle to Primary token to assign to the process.
>     // TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY access to this token is needed.
>     //
>
>     HANDLE Token;
>
>     //
>     // Handle to the initial thread of the process.
>     // A process's access token can only be changed if the process has
>     // no threads or a single thread that has not yet begun execution.
>     //
>     // N.B. This field is unused.
>     //
>
>     HANDLE Thread;
>
> } PROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN, *PPROCESS_ACCESS_TOKEN;
> ```

so note that

> **A process's access token can only be changed if the process has no threads or a single thread that has not yet begun execution.**

really on xp/2003 was less strict condition: from *PspAssignPrimaryToken* in wrk

> A primary token can only be replaced if the process has no threads, or
>       has one thread.

but begin from vista this added *that has not yet begun execution*

if you call it for self process (you may be need *SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege* privilege and can got `STATUS_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD` without it, depend on token type ) - you got `STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED` error. for [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/86602194-c8f7-4c42-b349-fd78e1bdb5f2/ntsetinformationprocess-processaccesstoken-fails-with-statusnotsupported?forum=windowssecurity)

so in practice we can only change process token just after we start process in suspended state (look for example this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13066468/6401656) ). but better use [`CreateProcessAsUserW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) function in this case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only way seems feasible is to prepare the token in the main thread and pass the same token to the new threads for them to impersonate. This way, the new threads themselves don't have to call `LogOnUser()` again. They just need to impersonate (the same token).

Comment: yes. you need got (somehow) impersonation token only once and then use `SetThreadToken` for set token for threads. you can pass this token for thread for it itself do this when/if need. or create thread in suspended state , call `SetThreadToken` and resume